# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Settings page not disappearing

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to remove the worklight settings on iOS. I've done "<worklightSettings include="false"/>" in my application-descriptior.xml under my iphone node. Then I deleted the iphone/native folder and regenerated it, but the settings still appear when I install the freshly generated native code from xcode. As I expected, the iphone/native folder does not contain a setting.bundle after building.

Worklight version 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900
Occurs on both iOS 6 and 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to Product > Clean the project in Xcode after the re-building in Eclipse.

If this somehow did not help, then:
Delete the app from the device / reset the iOS Simulator and re-run, then it will disappear. This is "cache residue" in the OS.

Comment: I've running it on a real device and I have been uninstalling the app before I reinstall it again.

Comment: In Xcode, before running the app, choose Product > Clean. Also verify that in Xcode you do not see the settings.bundle file.

Comment: Clean did it. Should have thought of that one. Thanks.